# Searching for index of object in a list

Tags: python

I went through some questions but could not find one that really helps.

Lets say I have a list of objects

```
[[Cheese(3), Cheese(2), Cheese(1)], []]
```

and I need to write a function that will find the index of Cheese(1) in there

I tried this:

```
def location (search):
    return self.list.index(Cheese(1))
```

Which didnt work, I thought `list.index(search)` returns the index of the searched item in a list?

For the above list the index should have been list[0][2] for Cheese(1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Give your `Cheese()` class an [`__eq__` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) so that Python knows when two instances hold the same value:

   ```
   class Cheese(object):
       def __init__(self, id):
           self.id = id

       def __eq__(self, other):
           if isinstance(other, Cheese):
               return self.id == other.id
           return NotImplemented
   ```

   With this implementation, two `Cheese()` instances are equal if they have the same `id` value.

   Without `__eq__` two references to `Cheese()` instances are only equal if it concerns the *same object* (identity).
2. `list.index()` does **not** search nested lists; you need to do so explicitly:

   ```
   search = Cheese(1)
   try:
       return next((i, sublist.index(search)) for i, sublist in enumerate(self.list) if search in sublist)
   except StopIteration:
       raise IndexError('{} not found in the list'.format(Cheese(1))
   ```

   would return a tuple with 2 indices into the outer and inner lists, representing the first location where `Cheese(1)` is found.

Demo:

```
>>> class Cheese(object):
...     def __init__(self, id):
...         self.id = id
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         if isinstance(other, Cheese):
...             return self.id == other.id
...         return NotImplemented
... 
>>> Cheese(1) == Cheese(1)
True
>>> Cheese(1) == Cheese(2)
False
>>> lst = [[Cheese(3), Cheese(2), Cheese(1)], []]
>>> next((i, sublist.index(Cheese(1))) for i, sublist in enumerate(lst) if Cheese(1) in sublist)
(0, 2)
```

Comment: Even the master is after all human ;-) There's a `Chees()` in there

Comment: @1_CR: `+++ OUT OF SLEEP ERROR +++ REDO FROM START +++`

Comment: How would I go about only returning the first index, ignoring all other index locations?

Comment: Oh sorry I dont think I made my self clear, lets say there will be no duplicate objects in the list, and I only need the 0, instead of the more specified (0,2). I think with this project I am working on there will only be 1 level of nested lists.

Comment: @NickGong: `next(i for i, sublist in outerlist if search in outerlist)` would do that.

Comment: my list was `[[Cheese(3), Cheese(2), Cheese(1)], [], [], []]` but it gave me an error ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @NickGong: Sorry, forgot the `enumerate()`: `next(i for i, sublist in enumerate(outerlist) if search in outerlist)`

Comment: should the last outerlist be sublist? since we are searching for Cheese(1) in the emunerated sublists? it didnt work for me until i changed it to sublist.

Comment: Aarg, yes, of course. Code comments on a mobile device are giving me gip, sorry.